# Application Data Redirection Permissions

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, file-permissions, folder-redirection

I setup application data redirection for my users (which is needed due to my users using different computers all the time and their expectation of getting the same user experience on each machine). Folder redirection works fine except for the app data folder, where several programs (not all of them) are having issues accessing and writing to the folder. Running it as admin doesnt help, I messed with permissions as much I could (I even went as far as temporarily setting permissions to give everyone full access) but no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some applications just don't work with folder redirection because they are having trouble with UNC paths. There's not much you can do about it except turn folder redirection off for AppData if you really need those applications or hope there's an update for the application that fixes the issue.